# Why is my post being created inside another post? [ Wordpress ]

Tags: wordpress, post

I know there is probably a solved question like this already, but I can't seem to find it.

I am just starting out so this may be a noob question, please bear with me ><

I am trying to display the top 3 recent posts on front-page.php of my site, the problem is that the post keeps being created within itself.

Here is the CSS involved.

```css
.news-container{ background-color: #fff;
                 padding: 2em;  
                 max-width: 600px; 
                 heigth:300px;
                 text-align: left;
}

.has-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 200px;
}


.post-thumbnail {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}


article.post { border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
               margin-bottom: 3em;
}

article.post:last-of-type { border-bottom: none;
}



Here is the front-page.php code involved.
```

```html
   <div class="news-container">   
       
       
 <?php

    
$recentposts=get_posts('showposts=5');
if ($recentposts) {
foreach($recentposts as $post) {
setup_postdata($post);
?>
       <article class="post <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?> has-thumbnail <?php } ?> ">
            
 <div class="post-thumbnail">          
 <?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail'); ?>    
 </div> 
           
        
<p><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> 
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title()?> </a></h3>
    <p>      
            <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Read more &raquo; </a> 
            <br><br> <br><br> <br><br>
            
            </p>
<?php   
}
}

           ?>
 </article>    
       
</div>
```

Why is this happening? Thanks for reading this!

Comment: you forgot to close `</p>`. You also do not have opening `<article>`. And you don't have anything with class `post` within `article`

Comment: Hi I did close the article tag with a conditional if statement.
<article class="post <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?> has-thumbnail <?php } ?> ">. Trying closing the <p>, didn't work :(

Comment: update your code so I can see it. Also, my bad, missed that opening  `article`

Comment: Hi Flyer, thanks for the help! It has been solved! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this updated code i think you not close all tags properly. This will solve your problem.

```
<div class="news-container">   
    <?php    
    $args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type'=>'post' );
    query_posts($args); $post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while($post_query->have_posts()){ $post_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <article class="post <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?> has-thumbnail <?php } ?> ">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">          
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail'); ?>    
        </div> 
        <p><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> </p>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title()?> </a></h3>
        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Read more &raquo; </a> 
            <br><br> <br><br> <br><br>
        </p>
    </article> 
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this with the WP Latest Posts Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-latest-posts/screenshots/